# Как из сайта на bitrix выгружать ссылки на фото в 1с?

Tags: php, html, битрикс, 1с

Пожалуйста подскажите, как можно выгрузить с сайта bitrix в 1С ссылку на фотографию товаров и ID товара?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос какой-то очень обобщенный.
Фотографии в инфоблоке? 1с 7 или 8? Как обмениваться будет информация?

В целом вот так можно детальные фотографии из инфоблока взять:

```
use Bitrix\Main\Loader;
Loader::includeModule('iblock');

$res = \Bitrix\Iblock\ElementTable::getList(
    [
        'filter' => [
            'IBLOCK_ID' => 10,
            'ACTIVE'    => 'Y'
        ],
        'select' => [
            'IBLOCK_ID', 'ID', 'DETAIL_PICTURE'
        ]
    ]
);

$links = [];
while ($item = $res->fetchObject())
{
    $links[$item->getId()] = CFile::GetPath($item->getDetailPicture());
}

if(count($links) > 0)
{
    \Bitrix\Main\Diag\Debug::dump($links);

    // do something
}
```

Ну а далее выгружать в текстовый файл, XML, csv и из 1с загружать файл, обрабатывать.

Comment: фотографии которые в инфоблоке "Каталог", прикрепленные к товарам, 1с 8, получается чтобы отправлялись данные в 1с через сайт.

Comment: Готового решения нет, это вам к разработчикам надо обращаться. Я привел код, как из инфоблока достать ID и путь к картинке. Битрикс и 1с синхронизируют позиции по XML_ID, а не по ID, как Вы спрашивали. Вам надо разработать выгрузку на сайте в файл, а в 1с разработать загрузку данных.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за ответ.